# How to fit curves to the menisci depicted in a series of images using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, batch-processing, curve-fitting

I have a series of images (*.bmp, in colour) depicting the evolution of the downstream meniscus during a slot-die coating process (see exemplary image in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4HTP.png)).

Now I would like to fit curves to the respective downstream meniscus in every single image (ideally via some sort of batch processing) using Matlab. The purpose being

- to obtain the equation of each of the fits in order to be able to
  quantify the change in the shape of the meniscus
- and to create a plot that includes all of the fit curves to illustrate the
  changes in the shape of the meniscus graphically.

I have started working on a code that does that for a single image. This is how far I got:

```
I = imread('//ImagePath');
Icrop = imcrop(I);
subplot(2,2,1);
imshow(I);

title('Original Image');
subplot(2,2,2);
imshow(Icrop);

title('Cropped Image');
BW = im2bw(Icrop, graythresh(Icrop));
subplot(2,2,3);
imshow(BW);

title('Cropped BW Image');
[B,L] = bwboundaries(BW,'noholes');
subplot(2,2,4);
imshow(L);

title('Crop Image with Boundaries Detected');
hold on
for k = 1:length(B)
    boundary = B{k};
    plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), 'r', 'LineWidth', 2)
end
```

Using this code, I currently get the results shown in [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLYId.png).

The questions I have are the following ones:

1. How can I avoid getting the straight horizontal / vertical part of
   the red line?
2. How can I fit a curve to the red line following the
   shape of the meniscus?
3. How do I do all of that for multiple images
   at once? (they all have the same size and show the same content
   besides the little variations in the shape of the meniscus)?
4. How can I then plot all the fit curves into one image?

I am fairly new to Matlab, so I would naturally appreciate any kind of hints / help / advice you can provide!

Thanks a lot! :)

P.S.: I know very well that the image quality is not the best.